# Related questions in the sidebar which are closed as dupe of the question you're currently looking at results in poor UX for anonyomous users

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, related-questions, user-experience

On AskUbuntu, there is [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error). In the sidebar, under "Linked questions", there is a link to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10664/how-do-i-fix-ubuntu-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode?lq=1), which has been closed as duplicate and merged with the first question.

For anonymous, not-logged-in users, duplicate questions automatically redirect to the dupe target.

In this case, this results in a poor user experience for anonymous users, since they click on the linked question in the sidebar, only to be taken back to where they were. My reaction when I experienced this while not logged in was pretty much "Huh, what's going on here ?".

I suggest that this is fixed, either by:

- Disabling the redirect (add `noredirect=1` to the URL) for such duplicate questions linked to in the sidebar
- Hide duplicate questions which are a duplicate of the question the user is currently looking at from the sidebar.

Comment: +1 I wouldn't call it a bug per se, but it certainly is a sensible feature request. After all, these are shown in the "Linked" section as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're passing `noredirect=1` now. (It may take a bit for caches to expire)

Comment: The implementation seems to be incomplete. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366421/clicking-on-vote-count-in-the-linked-questions-list-does-not-give-a-noredirect