# While logged out, trying to view posts from the list of linked duplicate posts which have no answers, redirects you to the duplicate "original" post

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, linked-questions, redirection

When logged in, you get to stay on the page of the question closed as a duplicate.

Consider this page: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/58032?lq=1

I got here by clicking the link "[see more linked questions…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/58032?lq=1)" in the right widget, and it has the `?lq=1` url parameter.

None of the links in the page with the list of linked questions have a `noredirect` parameter, which may still work out if you're logged in, but if you're logged out, you'll have to add it manually to the url if you want to view a closed duplicate question with 0 answers.

Comment: It was [fixed a while ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280895/related-questions-in-the-sidebar-which-are-closed-as-dupe-of-the-question-youre) for questions linked directly in the sidebar; I guess the "more linked" page got missed